# PySimpleGUI, Setting auto_size_button to False not working

Tags: python, button, pysimplegui

The button size seems always connected to the font size regardless of the auto_size_button state.
Even when auto_size_button is set to False, and button size should not be sized to fit the text, the button enlarges proportionally when choosing larger font size.
What am I missing?

```
    # ----- Menu Definition ----- #
    menu_def = [['Settings', ['Sound', 'Players', 'Points']]]

    # ----- Main GUI ----- #
    sg.theme('DarkAmber')
    layout = [[sg.Menu(menu_def, )],
              [sg.Text()],
              [sg.Button(str(eye), button_color="Orange", font=("", 10, "bold"), disabled=True, size=(10, 5),
                         auto_size_button=False, key=(str(eye))) for eye in range(1, 10)],
              [sg.Text('', key="-DICE1-", font=("arial", 150)), sg.Text('', key="-DICE2-", font=("arial", 150)),
               sg.Text('', key="-DICE_TOTAL-", font=("arial", 100))],
              [sg.Button('ROLL\n(Enter)', key="-ROLL-", size=(10, 5), bind_return_key=True),
               sg.Button('Cancel', size=(10, 5)),
               sg.Multiline('', size=(50, 5), key="-LOGBOX-", autoscroll=True),
               sg.Text('', key="-PLAYER-", font=("arial", 25))],
              [sg.Text()],
              ]

    # create the window
    return sg.Window('Shut The BOX', layout, return_keyboard_events=True, finalize=True, auto_close=False, \
                     enable_close_attempted_event=True, auto_size_buttons=False)
```

[Font_Size_10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nlv9l.jpg)
[Font_size_20](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rzh8Q.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

> auto_size_button
> if True the button size is sized to fit the text

> size
> (w, h) w=characters-wide, h=rows-high. If an int instead of a tuple is supplied, then height is auto-set to 1

The size of button is defined by option `size` in width, height of character or font.

Following code show to set the size of button in pixels by using image, here the size of button won't change as the font size.

`````py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

# PNG image with size 1x1 and color (0, 0, 0, 0)
image_data = b'\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x01\x08\x06\x00\x00\x00\x1f\x15\xc4\x89\x00\x00\x00\rIDATx\x9cc````\x00\x00\x00\x05\x00\x01\xa5\xf6E@\x00\x00\x00\x00IEND\xaeB`\x82'

layout = [
    [sg.Button(str(i), image_data=image_data, font=("", 10+i*1, "bold"), image_size=(80, 80))
        for i in range(1, 10)],
    ]
sg.Window('Shut The BOX', layout, finalize=True).read(close=True)
`````

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick reply. 
It is clear to me now.
Using a transparent pixel as image indeed solves the problem. 
It does feel like a workaround but I'm glad it works.